# In the game 2048, what is the biggest theoretical tile?

Tags: algorithm, game-theory

In the game [2048](http://gabrielecirulli.github.io/2048/) what is the biggest tile that can be achieved, assuming a player playing optimally and tile spawning at the most optimal place?

Naively I would say that the biggest achievable tile is `65536 * 2 = 131072` because it seems that the best possible board is the following:

```
  4     4     8     16
 256   128    64    32
 512   1024  2048  4096
65536 32768 16384  8192
```

But I'm not sure if

1. it's correct
2. how to prove that my intuition is indeed correct.

(sorry if I should have asked on [gaming.stackexchange](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/ask), but this is more of a CS question than a gaming one afaict)

Comment: if this is a CS question you should have asked on http://cs.stackexchange.com/ ;)

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is a theoretical CS question, not a programming question.

Comment: off, but there is no such a thing _most optimal_, there is only one _optimal_ solution. which is different from that is not _optimal_ anymore.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

you haven't finished yet with the board you propose: you can slide to the right, going all the way down and obtaining 131072. So your analysis was correct although you missed a spot:

This will be your final board:

```
  4     8     16    32
 512   256   128    64
 1024  2048  4096  8192
131072 65536 32768 16384
```

Comment: this is not possible, look 5 moves back and you will see that you do not have enough space to create an 8

Comment: I'm sorry but I fail to see the problem: look at the position proposed by @foo in his question; suppose you have his top line and my 3 bottom lines. Then you go like this: 4 8 8 16 --> 4 4 16 16 --> 4 [] 8 32 --> 4 4 8 32 --> 4 8 8 32 --> 4 4 16 32 --> 4 8 16 32...

Comment: we are talking about the theoretically best solution; "tiles spawning in the most optimal place"; the whole thing is unlikely :)